# What is the best way to join 1 table on two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have searched and seen other similar questions but nothing has helped me.

Here's examples of the tables I have:

dbo.Product

```
PRODUCTID | LEVEL | SOMEFIELD1 | SOMEFIELD2
500         01      Blue         Large
450         102     Black        Large
....
250         03      Orange       Medium
```

dbo.Level

```
LEVEL | ProductID
01      500
102     450
104     400 
02      350
101     300
03      250
```

dbo.LevelMap

```
LEVEL1 | LEVEL2
01       101
01       102
01       103
02       104
02       105
02       106
```

My join at the moment is very slow because I'm doing it like this:

```
SELECT
p1.ProductID
lm1.Level1,
lm1.Level2,
... -- other fields from other tables here
FROM
dbo.Product p1,
INNER JOIN 
dbo.Level l1 ON 
l1.ProductID = p1.ProductID
LEFT JOIN dbo.LevelMap lm1
    ON (l1.Level = lm1.Level1 OR
       l1.Level = lm1.Level2)
```

I'm joining `dbo.LevelMap lm1` twice using an OR statement. I want to avoid using a UNION because the actual SQL code is huge and I'll find it hard to maintain two sets of the code (one for each union).

All I want to do is return all the `Level1` and `Level2` for the given `Level`. The `dbo.Level` table contains a mix of Level1 and Level2 values hence I need to join twice to the `dbo.LevelMap` table. Here's what an ideal resultset would look like when a ProductID value of `400` is passed:

```
PRODUCTID | LEVEL1 | LEVEL2
400         02       104
```

In the JOIN it sees the value 104, matches it on the LEVEL2 column, and then gets its corresponding LEVEL1 value.

The problem is that this is running extremely slow because of the `OR` in the join. The tables have thousands of records to match on.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking to do is this:

"Find where 104 exists in either column LevelMap.Level1 or LevelMap.Level2"

If that's the case then you can do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM LevelMap map
WHERE map.Level1 = '104' OR map.Level2 = '104'
```

If that returns the correct results from LevelMap you can join on the Level table just once.

Option #2, join twice and take what you need:

```
SELECT l1.Column1, l2.Column2
FROM LevelMap map
     INNER JOIN Level l1 ON (map.Level1 = l1.Level)
     INNER JOIN Level l2 ON (map.Level2 = l2.Level)
WHERE map.Level1 = '104' OR map.Level2 = '104'
```

The nice thing about this is that you're doing two inner joins.

Comment: But now you've got rid of the table dbo.Level which is what LevelMap joins on. Or else theres no way to include LevelMap in the statement. The code I have given is just a small fraction of the entire SQL code but its the part thats causing complete slowdown.

Comment: see my option #2 I just added.

Comment: I have updated my question to better reflect the situation. I think I oversimplified it and removed an important table, dbo.Product. Could you be so kind as to suggest how I could tackle it?

Comment: The example is getting a bit complicated now.  If you can create a SQL fiddle that creates sample tables with sample data it may make it more clear.  Plus then we could just update the fiddle with the solution.

http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1):

That left join makes no sense to me as l1 is not even returned

An OR is typically very hard on a join as it goes into a loop
First put indexes on those columns

I just now saw the condition
Like I said that left has no purpose (that I can see)

```
SELECT
    lm1.Level1,
    lm1.Level2
FROM
    dbo.Level l1
JOIN dbo.LevelMap lm1 
    ON l1.Level = 104  
   AND (    l1.Level = lm1.Level1 
         OR l1.Level = lm1.Level2 )
```

I bet you get better performance with this
So you have to maintain separate queries

```
SELECT
     lm1.Level1,
     lm1.Level2
FROM
     dbo.Level l1
JOIN dbo.LevelMap lm1 
  ON l1.Level = 104
 AND l1.Level = lm1.Level1 
UNION 
SELECT
     lm1.Level1,
     lm1.Level2
FROM
     dbo.Level l1
JOIN dbo.LevelMap lm1
  ON l1.Level = 104
 AND l1.Level = lm1.Level2
```

This just does not appear to be 3NF
I suspect your query problems are the product of bad data design

Comment: I have updated my question to better reflect the situation. I think I oversimplified it and removed an important table, dbo.Product. Could you be so kind as to suggest how I could tackle it? Yes its probably bad design but I am stuck with it and can't change it :(

Comment: Did you try the queries I proposed?